# Jquery calling the action on change event and then reflecting the value in a div form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

I have a sj:select drop down. On change event of that drop down. I am trying to invoke a action.

```
    $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : 'getAttributeTypeForUpdate',
                        data : param,
                        success : function(data) {
                            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                            alert(data.attributeTypeObj.typeName)
                        },
                        async : false
                    });
```

In the action I am returning attributeTypeObj. Below is just the annotation I am Using.

```
@SkipValidation
@Action(value="getAttributeTypeForUpdate", 
results={
        @Result(name = SUCCESS, type = JSON, params = {
                "ignoreHierarchy", "false",
                "includeProperties", "attributeTypeObj\\..*, actionMessages\\[\\d+\\]"
        })          
})
```

I am able to get the data in alert box of action class. But the div form which I am using to reflect the values is not displaying.

```
    <div id="updateAttributeType" class="updateAttributeType"
                        style="width: 900px;" align="center">


                            <div class=table-row>
                                <div class="col3">
                                    <b><s:label id="lb20">Type Name:</s:label></b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col3">
                                    <s:textfield name="typeName" id="typeName"
                                        cssStyle="width: 250px;" labelposition="left"
                                        value="%{#attributeTypeObj.typeName}"></s:textfield>
                                </div>
```

I have used the following publish "$.publish("updateAttributeType"); " after the ajax call. The value is empty still.

```
    %{#attributeTypeObj.typeName}
```

Comment: *Reflecting the value* by magic? Don't see any code about updating field value.

Comment: @AleksandrM I was expecting value="%{#attributeTypeObj.typeName}" to populate on ajax call. But later realized that its part of DOM. I need to refresh whole page or write the html value instead. I have opted the second choice.

Comment: If you have solved the question then self-answer it and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was expecting value="%{#attributeTypeObj.typeName}" to populate on ajax call. But later realized that its part of DOM. I need to refresh whole page or write the html value instead. I have opted the second choice and wrote values of the tags on the jquery like:

```
$('#uptypeName').val(data.attributeTypeObj.typeName);
```